# Using ASP.NET server button to read HTML added by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET page in which I implemented drag and drop animations using jQuery.

The page contains a div as a draggable one and a second as a droppable that acts like a shopping cart. I need to click an ASP.NET button to save the dropped items and their quantities in a SQL Server database.
For the button to save data to database, I have the following code

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
// Get the stream from the returned web response
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
string strLine;
while ((strLine = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Ignore blank lines
    if (strLine.Length > 0)
        sb.Append(strLine);
}
// Finished with the stream so close it now
stream.Close();
```

But for bad luck, the `sb.ToString()` returns the HTML without the HTML added by jQuery on runtime. For example if I drop three products in the shopping cart it should have appeared in HTML like `ul` containing three `li`'s items but it appears as empty `ul`. But if I click on browser on inspect element on Chrome I see those `li`'s.

Comment: thanks Saqib , but this doesn't solve the problem ,I still can't see dropped item on page source on server button click :(

Comment: Why you're using WebRequest? Is it on same server or not? Anyway... I believe that in your case much better solution is to use jQuery ajax call with webmethod or web serrvice or controller (depend of wich pattern you're using).

Comment: It's on the same server , so  what should I use instead of WebRequest?

Comment: I told alredy - jQuery ajax call + web method or web service in case of web forms or jQuery ajax call + controller in case of web api or mvc. This will allow you to save data of the items in shopping cart.

Comment: Thanks @andrey.shedko , could you please provide me with useful links in using jquery ajax call + web method to save data on shopping cart ?

Comment: There is huge number of tutorials on the web, but these two I like: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ and http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/